# Understanding the relationship between derivatives and linear transformations

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Suppose I have a function $f : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$, then $f$ is differentiable at $a$ if there exists a $n \times m$ matrix $B_a$ such that $$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-B_a\cdot h}{|h|} = 0$$

Now we can identify $B_a$ with a linear transformation as follows. Define $T : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ by $$T(x) = B_a\cdot x$$ then we can also call $T$ the derivative of $f$ at $a$.

If $f$ is differentiable for each $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$, then the *derivative* of $f$ is the function $Df : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ defined by $$Df(a) = B_a \cdot a$$

(Take note that I haven't actually seen a definition of the derivative as a function in the way I said in the last paragraph, so I may possibly be wrong, if so please correct me)

Now the way I understand it is that although the derivative of $f$ at a point $a$ (which is $T$ above) is a linear transformation, the *derivative* of $f$, $Df$, need not be a linear transformation.

Because if the derivative $Dg$ of any arbitrary function $g$ was a linear transformation then $Dg$ would be continuous and since the $D(Dg) = Dg$ since $Dg$ is a linear transformation we would have that $g \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^m)$ so that any arbitrary differentiable function $g$ would be smooth which is clearly a contradiction since we can find counterexamples.

Am I correct in what I said above?

Comment: Your definition is incorrect: $Df(a)$ is the map $T$ itself, not $T(a)$

Comment: _"Now the way I understand it is that although the derivative of f at a point a (which is T above) is a linear transformation, the derivative of f, Df, need not be a linear transformation."_ Also this sentence doesn't make sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Definition.** A function $f:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^n$ is differentiable at $a\in\mathbb R^m$ if there exists a linear transformation $T:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^n$ such that
$$
\lim_{h\to0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-T(h)}{|h|} = 0.
$$
If it exists, this transformation is unique and is denoted by $Df(a)$.

Therefore, at each point of differentiability $a\in\mathbb R^m$, the derivative $Df(a)$ is by definition a linear transformation $\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R^n$, which can of course be represented with respect to the canonical bases by the [Jacobian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) $J_f(a)$.

What you seem to be saying is that the maps $a\mapsto Df(a)$ or $a\mapsto J_f(a)$ are linear. This is of course false in general (it is true iff $f$ is quadratic).

You also seem to define the derivative as the map $a\mapsto Df(a)(a)$. This also is incorrect. The definition is the one given above.

Comment: So then if $Df(a)$ is the linear map $T_a$ itself (I added the subscript to $T$ just for brevity), and $Df(a)$ is the derivative of $f$ at the point $a$, and I want to express *the derivative of $f$* on $\mathbb{R}^m$ to be the function $Df$ sending $a$ to the derivative of $f$ at $a$, then is the function $Df : \mathbb{R}^m \to L(\mathbb{R}^m, \mathbb{R}^n)$ defined by $Df(a) = T_a$ the correct *derivative* of $f$?

Comment: Yes, you are correct in your last statement. You have the derivative at a point given by $Df(a)$, and then you can consider the "derivative" as being the map $a\mapsto Df(a)$ that to each point associates the derivative computed at it, and this is a function $\mathbb R^m\to L(\mathbb R^m,\mathbb R^n)$ with no further regularity, in general. Notice for instance that in the one dimensional case $f'(a)$ is identified with the linear map $y\mapsto f'(a)y$. The map $a\mapsto f'(a)$ has no "regularity" (apart from [Darboux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis)), for instance)

Comment: When you say that a function $f$ is $C^1$, you mean that this new function $Df:\mathbb R^m\to L(\mathbb R^m,\mathbb R^n):a\mapsto Df(a)$ is indeed a $C^1$ function

Comment: So then when people say that *"if $f : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ is a linear transformation, then $Df = f$"*, what they really mean is that $Df(a) = f$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}^m$, but $Df$ does't truly equal $f$ set theoretically, since they have different codomains.

Comment: People usually say "if $f$ is linear, its derivative *at any point* equals $f$ itself". This means $[Df(a)](y)=f(y)$. In this case, $Df$ is a *constant* map, taking only the value $f$.

Comment: Think also in the 1D case: if $f(t)=ct$ is linear, then the derivative $f'(a)=c$ is constant with respect to the point at which you compute it.

Comment: Only when $m=1$ you can identify $\mathbb R^n\simeq L(\mathbb R^m,\mathbb R^n)$ and think of both $f$ and $Df$ as maps $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R^n$. This is what happens on the 1D case, where we usually think $f,f':\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: Just one last question, $Df$ is not linear is it? Thanks for your comments, they've been really helpful!

Comment: $Df:\mathbb R^m\to L(\mathbb R^m,\mathbb R)$ is linear if and only if $f:\mathbb R^m\to\mathbb R$ is quadratic, in the sense that $f(x) = x^TAx$ for some symmetric $m\times m$ matrix $A$. Indeed you can verify that in this case $[Df(a)](y) = 2a^TAy$, so $a\mapsto 2a^TA$ is linear.

Comment: I forgot a term: the equivalence is "if and only if $f(x)=x^TAx+b$"